# Javascript map with index to json

Tags: javascript, json

I have an array of images

```
[ "foto7.jpg", "foto3.jpg", "foto5.jpg"]
```

I'm trying to shuffle it and then map it to an hash with a predefined structure.
My function now is (vue computed properties)

```
randomDataset: function () {
      var array = this.shuffleArray(this.images)
      return array.map((currElement, index) => {
        var hash = {};
        hash['reference']= index+1;
        hash['image']= currElement
        return hash
      });

    }
  }
```

and the output is

```
[ { "reference": 1, "image": "foto8.jpg" }, { "reference": 2, "image": "foto6.jpg" }..]
```

I cannot find a way to have a structure like this

```
{
  "images": {
    "1": {
      "image_url": "www....",
      "image_reference": "1"
    },
    "2": {
      "image_url": "www....",
      "image_reference": "2"
    }
  }
}
```

The numbers (1,2...etc) are the index of the array I'm mapping, and the image url is the array value. How can I do?

Comment: Use a _map_ when you want apply one function to each element of an array, so the result is another array with the same size of the original  and where each element is the result of the function application to the corresponding element in the original array. The operation described in your example is a _reduce_, you want to transform the array in a single _object_, look the example of this operation  bellow in _@Hassan Imam_ 's answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `array#reduce` to push your image url into an object.

```js
const array = [ "foto7.jpg", "foto3.jpg", "foto5.jpg"],
result = array.reduce((res, url, index) => {
  res.images[index + 1] = {"image_url": url, "image_reference": index + 1};
  return res;
},{"images":{}});
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```